# Magento 2 Change position of tabs in admin order view page

Tags: magento2

I am adding a new tab on orders page. I have made sales_order_view.xml in my module. Its code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>          
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_label</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">DL\Labelprinting\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom</argument>

            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

But this tab is appearing as first tab on orders view page. I want to appear it in last

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use action method `addTabAfter` instead of `addTab` and add argument `after` to add custom tab after particular tab**

So your final custom tab should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
                <action method="addTabAfter">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_label</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Custom</argument>
                    <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks @Price this helps to solve my problem